# Excluding BuildConfig.class and R.class from Android library jar in Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, build, jar

I'm using the Maven Android plugin to build my Android library using the `apklib` packaging. This produces an `apklib` archive of the library, so I'm also using the Maven jar plugin to produce a jar artifact that can be used in an app.

My problem is that `BuildConfig.class` and `R.class` are being included in the jar, which I don't want (really I would like to exclude anything in `gen` altogether). I've been trying to create `exclude` rules for them but haven't had any success. Here's the jar plugin configuration I've been using in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>              
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/BuildConfig.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/R.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you run `mvn help:effective-pom`, do your `<exclude>`s end up pointing to the right `.java` files?

Comment: @connor.brinton That yields the same thing (e.g. `**/BuildConfig.java`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to apply your configuration to the `default-jar` phase of the build lifecycle and exclude `.class` files, rather than `.java` files. You do this by adding `<id>default-jar</id>` to your execution as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>  
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/BuildConfig.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/R.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You'll probably also want to exclude the classes `R$attr.class`, `R$drawable.class`, `R$layout.class`, and `R$string.class`.

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the problem. Any chance you'd know why the GPG plugin would be signing the jars created by `maven-source-plugin` and `maven-javadoc-plugin` but not `maven-jar-plugin`?